# What types of equipment work when driving a spidertron?

Tags: factorio

For example, personal laser defenses and personal roboports work from the driver's equipment grid, but exoskeletons and belt immunity equipment do not. (Instead they need to be equipped in the spidertron's own equipment grid.) Is there a complete list anywhere of what driver equipment works and what doesn't?

Comment: If you hover above a piece of equipment, the pop-up will tell you where that equipment can fit into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From testing around, only equipment related to movement has to be equipped in the spidertron's own grid in order to work. That means only the exoskeleton and the belt immunity equipment. Interestingly enough, nightvision also works from the spidertron's equipment grid.